# Checking domain headers curl and grep

Tags: curl, grep

I am a beginner. I am checking HTTP headers on a list of domains. The following works if the grep succeeds. If it doesn't the loop prints the results of the next line on the same line. I want it to print an error "000" after the domain and then go to a new line if the grep doesn't find HTTP. I have tried if else fi but I get an error on the else part.

```
    filename="$1"
    while read -r line
    do
        domain=$line
        printf "$domain," 
        curl -m3 -I http://www."$domain" 2>&1 | grep "HTTP/" | awk '{print $2}'   
    done < "domains.txt"
```

Comment: filename variable is never used

Answer (score 0):

Demo :

```
$ bash curl.sh
free.fr 301
google.com 302
foobar.tld error 000
```

input file domains.txt :

```
free.fr
google.com
foobar.tld
```

The script :

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    domain="$line"
    tempvar=$(curl -m3 -I "http://www.$domain" 2>&1 |
        awk '/HTTP\//{print $2}')
    # testing if $tempvar exists (not null)
    if [[ $tempvar ]]; then
        echo  "$domain $tempvar"
    else
        echo >&2 "$domain error 000"
    fi
done < "domains.txt"
```